# Trying to send an acknowledgement email when a row is added to a Google Sheet from Squarespace Form Submit Button

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am a new user of Google App Scripts. What I am trying to do with my Google App Script is send a user an acknowledgement email when they hit the submit button on a Squarespace form.

1. I have configured the Squarespace form, submit button to be stored in a Google Sheet.  I have tested that and it is working as expected.
2. Next, I created a Google Apps Script by opening my Google Sheet that collects the form submissions, clicked on Extensions, and selected Apps Script.
3. Next I added the following in the script editor:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  // Get the form submission data
  var formData = e.namedValues;
  var recipientEmail = formData['Email Address'][0]; // Replace 'Email' with your form's email field label
  var recipientName = formData['Name'][0]; // Replace 'Name' with your form's name field label, if applicable
  
  // Email details
  var subject = "Thank you for your submission!";
  var body = "Dear " + recipientName + ",\n\n" + // Modify this message as necessary
             "Thank you for reaching out to us. We have received your submission and will get back to you soon.\n\n" +
             "Best Regards,\nYour Team"; // Customize this signature

  // Send the email
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipientEmail, subject, body);
}
```

4. Next I setup a trigger with the following:

- Selected the function to run: onFormSubmit
- Selected deployment : Head
- Select event source: From spreadsheet
- Select event type: On form submit

Finally, after going through the authorization prompts, I saved the script.  When I attempt to execute the script I receive the following error:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'namedValues')
onFormSubmit    @ Code.gs:3

I am unsure of how to resolve this issue.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for your help.

Denise

Here are some screen shots:

[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DN3w.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDakV.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Nb1r.png)

Comment: About `When I attempt to execute the script I receive the following error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'namedValues') onFormSubmit @ Code.gs:3`, how did you run your showing script? I guessed that you might have wanted to run your script by the OnSubmit trigger. But, from the error message, I'm worried that you directly ran your showing script with the script editor. If my guess was correct, unfortunately, such an error occurs because of no event object `e`. If my understanidng is correct, how about executing it with the OnSubmit trigger?

Comment: When I saw your question, it seemed that your function `onFormSubmit` has already been installed as the OnSubmit trigger at `Next I setup a trigger with the following:`. If my understanding is correct, when you submit the Google Form, the function `onFormSubmit` is automatically run with the OnSubmit trigger. But, if I misunderstood your current situation, I apologize.

Comment: Hi Tanaike - thanks for your reply.  I'm not following your response exactly.  I did try to execute the script from within the script editor and that's when I received the error.  I am not using a Google Form, but rather I have the Submit button on a Squarespace form which is configured to store submissions in the Google Sheet.  I did run several tests with my test Squarespace form and while I see entries in the spreadsheet, no acknowledgement email is being sent.

Comment: When you run the function from the script editor the trigger is not able to supply the event object to populate the first parameter so you must do it with an intermediate function